# Upvote or downvote? Guideline is somewhat confusing

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Probably this has been already discussed but I failed to find a thread, so let me ask again.

The upvote tooltip says

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

and the downvote tooltip goes

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Now, one can easily imagine a question that *is useful* because it exists and has useful *answers* but shows no research effort whatsoever. Moreover, this can be an old question and SO standards were different (which is probably irrelevant). So, should I read the first tooltip as

> This question shows research effort **and** it is useful **and** clear

and the other one means that at least one of these is not true?

Here's a particular case: [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost) is helpful because it has an amount of useful *answers*, so I'm willing to upvote it; on the other hand it shows zero efforts, just none, so at the same time I'm inclined to downvote it. Ehmm... What do you think is a proper action?

Think of this question as of a necessary stage to propose a clarified version of the tooltip.

Comment: So, the only reason the question is useful is that the answers on it is useful? Is that correct?

Comment: Y think the ; implies and.

Comment: @Kendra in this particular case (and many others) yes, that's correct

Comment: But is that specifically what your question is about, or is it also for cases where the question, regardless of answers, is useful but also poorly researched? I'm just trying to make sure I understand the scope before I take a stab at the answer.

Comment: A __question__ doesn't become useful just because it has good __answers__. Vote on a question as if there are no answers.

Comment: A question being sufficiently well researched is simply *an important thing for it to do in order for it to be useful*.  Important enough that it's specifically called out in the tool tip.  If the answer to the question is trivially found when searching then even if it has the correct answer posted as an answer it's not really useful because you'd have gotten the answer just as easily even if the question didn't exist.  Also note that a question needing to be researched is not new.  It has always been expected of questions.

Comment: @Kendra well, if you cover that particular case it is sufficient; actually I can hardly see the difference. Can you provide an example? (of cases where the question, regardless of answers, is useful but also poorly researched)

Comment: 0.075% of the people that looked at the Q+A voted the question helpful.  Still impressed?  Probably because some people are just thankful for Google ranking it, the only real way to ever get a quarter of a million views.  That kind of SEO is never very obvious btw.

Comment: I can't, and that's why I wasn't sure I could answer it if your question wasn't specifically about the first case. I'll work on an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votes on a post should be based on the merits of *that post* alone, regardless of (other) answers on the Q&A page.

So, if a question is, by itself and regardless of answers, poorly researched, unclear, or not useful, then it certainly meets the criteria for downvoting.

If the question is worth a downvote, but the answers are incredibly useful? The question is still worth a downvote. The *answers* may certainly be worth an upvote, but they need to be considered in a vacuum of sorts as well.

Now, if an answer is an obvious duplicate, then that is the only, as far as I can tell, reason to use another post to decide your vote. However, an obvious duplicate meets the clear criteria of "poorly researched" in this case, so to me, that makes sense.

In the end, of course, votes are yours to do with as you please, barring voting fraud. So really, if you *feel* that the usefulness of a post outweighs the poor research effort, if that case should arise for you, then it's up to you to decide if it outweighs it enough for an upvote, or just enough to cancel your downvote urges.

Comment: Sounds fair enough. I'd say commas in the tooltips would be less confusing than semicolons.

Comment: Another thing to note is.. this is not how it actuall works! The post got 159 upvotes and no downvotes before my post. People just upvote most probably in terms of "me too" and "helpful answers". That's something to consider.

Comment: That people aren't downvoting by the guidelines doesn't mean the guidelines should change- You asked about the guidelines, so... I answered about them. Like I said in the last paragraph, aside from fraud, people can vote as they please really. Also note that you said that's an old post, so a number of the upvotes my have come while it was considered a good post, and people have upvoted it more since for various reasons.

Comment: Sure, I'm not thinking about changing guidelines but about the interface which is a sort of guideline (makes people tend to do something) by its own