# Should the tooltip for the question upvote button only mention "usefulness"?

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, tooltips

### In short

As I read them, the tooltip for the *upvote* button for *Questions* on SO, and the corresponding help-center page for the ["vote up" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), are not completely consistent. The latter mentions only *usefulness* as a reason to vote up, whereas the former mentions also *research effort* and *clarity*.

Should the two be consolidated? If not, why not?

### Details

The tooltip for the *upvote* button for *Questions* on SO reads as follows:

> This question shows *research effort*; it is *useful* and *clear*

(my emphasis)

I believe this may lead to discussions like [Can / should up votes be separated from "Me too" votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258151) and ["Me too" button and auto-bounties from Community for high-quality questions without answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341853).

At least, it did for me. For example, I remember one of the highest voted questions on SO, regarding `git pull` vs `fetch`, which contains only one line, and is very clearly answered in the `git` documentation (although I don't know if that has always been the case). I consider this question useful and clear, but it does not *reflect* any research effort (this does not necessarily mean the OP did not *do* any research). Confused by the tooltips, I ended up not voting at all.

Based on these discussions, the consensus seems to be that *usefulness* of a question outweighs *research effort* and *clarity*.

The [SO help-center page for the "vote up" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) appears to support this impression, as it explicitly mentions only *usefulness*:

> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially *useful*, vote it up!

No mention of research effort or clarity here. Might it be an idea to reflect this in the corresponding tooltip as well?

EDIT: Or perhaps change the order of the current tooltip, e.g. "This question is useful; it is clear and shows research effort?"

I think people are more likely to read the tooltip than the help-center page(s).

Note that the upvote tooltip for Answers *does* simply say "This answer is useful."

### Similar discussions

Although very similar to these questions, among others, my question applies specifically to the upvote button and the corresponding documentation in the SO help-center.

- [Upvote or downvote? Guideline is somewhat confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366554)
- [When is it preferred to UP-vote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253729)
- [Are the two downvote tooltip reasons meant conjunctively or disjunctively?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251980/are-the-two-downvote-tooltip-reasons-meant-conjunctively-or-disjunctively)
- [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677)

Comment: _"Based on these discussions, the consensus seems to be that usefulness of a question outweighs research effort and clarity. "_ While one of those two factors  implies the other, I'd say that there is no need to dumb the tooltip down. Very often I find myself downvoting questions from the lack of research effort in them. If they can search Duck Duck Go (or the official guide of a technology if applicable) and easily find what they were looking for, then the question was not needed in the first place, making it significantly less useful. The tooltip clarifies that such a vote is reasonable.

Comment: @Cerbrus: thanks for the link. That clarifies a lot. On the same note, reading the part about votes for feature requests, I would expect a tooltip like "agree" or "disagree." (Not a recommendation, just trying to understand.)

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays: Please do not read this as a criticism, but, if "one of those two factors implies the other," doesn't that mean the "other" is redundant? Wouldn't that be all the more reason to modify the tooltip?

Comment: That is correct, I admitted the potential redundancy. :) On the other hand, I believe that there is no harm in keeping this relation explicit: research effort is a key component of a question's success on this site, much more in recent years than it was at the early days of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Research effort and clarity are not mentioned because they're two independent qualities of a question's usefulness, they're mentioned because they're the two of the most important factors in determining a post's usefulness.  They're *so* important that it's worth adding them to the tooltip, rather than hoping that readers will be able to realize what "usefulness" means for a question without any additional context.

Adding an entire paragraph or more, to go into some detail in what makes a question useful, would be unreasonable (that information is in the help center for people looking for more information than belongs in a tooltip).  But adding 5 short words, in exchange for making it much easier to understand for newer users, is absolutely worth the space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I completely agree that research effort and clarity are very important factors. That is not my point. My point is exactly that that information *is* in the tooltip, but *is not* in the help center page. Maybe my question should be the other way round: "Should research effort and clarity also be mentioned in the [help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (not only in the tooltip)?"

Comment: @djvg The help center has an entire *section* of pages on how to ask a good question, which all encompass the information of what makes a question useful.  That information already exists in the help center, just not on the page that described what the vote up privilege is, because that's not where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks. That last one would make a good answer. I'm probably looking at the whole thing from the wrong perspective.